# Is it acceptable to call teachings such as "How to behave as a Muslim" a science? If not, what should we call them in English?

Tags: science, religion

In the Muslim world, it is very popular to call the teachings of the religion a science. As we all know, the God and resurrection cannot be proven or rejected in a lab or through scientific methods. Therefore, is it acceptable to call teachings such as "How to behave as a Muslim" a science? If not, what should we call them in English?

Comment: That is a philosophical rather than an English question.  Medieval Muslim scientists were clear about the distinction

Comment: My faith in God is a matter of documented evidence and experimental knowledge. I regard my knowledge of Him as _more_ scientific than any other form of knowledge. And I am, by qualification, a scientist - Licentiate of the Royal Society.

Comment: There is a difference however, between *personal* belief systems (religion based on actual life experiences and first-hand knowledge) and *shared* belief systems (officially established religions based on formally organized doctrine which must be taught and learned from others).

Comment: Even though this is a question about the language behavior in English, you may get a better answer on [Islam.SE](https://islam.stackexchange.com). In English, the word 'science' isn't usually used to refer to religious tenets or behaviors, but in the domain of Islamic teachings, that may very well be the  usage (I don't know I'm just saying it is a possibility). And those well versed in that domain, at Islam.SE here, would know better. It is not implausible given the more English cultural connections via 'Christian Science' (though I am unaware if they use 'science' as you suggest.)

Comment: That said, it would sound very jarring to most English speakers to use 'science' for 'religious teachings'.

Answer (score 2):

In Masjed (Mosque) we learn it as a doctrine.
In school we study it as a subject.
In university or advanced study of Islam, we can call it "jurisprudence," or simply "fiqh (derived from Arabic word)."

Answer (score -1):

Okay I'm going to try and put this as neutrally as I can I apologise for any offense. I personally respect the teachings of any faith, but generally from a scientific point of view such material is call mythology. This is not to say that the material recorded is in any way untrue but it does denote material that cannot be date verified because of the *way* it has been recorded, the bible, the Torah, the Norse Sagas, the Illiad, and the Quran are all like this; some of what is recorded can be verified and some cannot and most importantly they're not told in a completely linear order of timing. This is usually a symptom of oral history or traditions being written down and [codified](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/codify) at a later date, this is certainly true of large parts of the bible, the Illiad and the Sagas.

The stories told in such texts are [lore](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lore).

The rules laid down by religious teachings are either doctrine, dogma, or law depending who you ask.

Hopefully that helps you.